# Remove radio button using values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my dashboard there are 4 radio button. I need show only one in one condition. And each button has different values

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method" value="Online-Others">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method" value="Cash">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method" value="wallet">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method" value="online">
```

Here I need to show only cash button. Should I make different ids for each button? Or using this am I able to show that?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: ids should be unique.

Comment: *"Should I make different ids for each button?"* - Sometimes you don't need to use element ids, but if you do use them you should *always* make them unique.

Comment: `id` should be unique for all elements inside an html page. And your question is not so clear

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements by values with a attribute selector:

```
// removes all 'payment_method' radios where 'value' is not 'Cash'
$(".payment_method[value!=Cash]").remove();
```

But as `ids` are unique in HTML, you could (*must*) better change them:

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_others" value="Online-Others">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_cash" value="Cash">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_wallet" value="wallet">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_online" value="online">
```

JS:

```
// removes all 'payment_method' radios where 'id' is not 'payment_method_cash'
$(".payment_method:not(#payment_method_cash)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add ID or Class

```
    $('input[name=payment_method][value=wallet]').prop('checked',true); //if you need to highlight "wallet"
    $('input[name=payment_method][value=Cash]').prop('checked',true); //if you need to highlight "Cash"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question in not much clear for me, are you expecting something like this ?

```js
$('#payment_method_cash').on('change', function() {

  // Show cash payment button and options.
  console.log('Cash option checked : ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('#payment_method_wallet').on('change', function() {

  // Show wallet payment button and options.
  console.log('wallet option checked : ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('#payment_method_online').on('change', function() {

  // Show online payment button and options.
  console.log('online option checked : ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
});


$('#payment_method_other').on('change', function() {

  // Show other payment button and options.
  console.log('Other option checked : ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_other" value="Online-Others">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_cash" value="Cash">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_wallet" value="wallet">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="payment_method_online" value="online">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `id` attribute and can use `value` attribute.

html

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method"  value="Online-Others">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method"  value="Cash">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method"  value="wallet">
<input type="radio" name="payment_method"  value="online">
```

jquery code will be like

```
//if you want to show only Cash radio button

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[value!='Cash']").css('display','none');
 });
```

Alternately if you want to checked one radio button out of four use below jquery.

```
//if you want to checked Cash radio button out of four use below

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[value='Cash']").attr('checked','true');
   });
```

Hope it will help.